# SystemModelLinearize

Tags: matrix, variable-definitions

The following are the state matrices A and B obtained by linearization using SystemModelLinearize ("DocumentationExamples. Modeling. Generator" is the circuit given by the official routine). I want to change this type of variable(Quantity variable) in the matrix to a variable that can be assigned(R1、R2、L), or to a variable that we define ourselves. What should I do?

If the case cannot run normally, you can open the website(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemModelLinearize.html.zh). The case is probably in the middle of the page.The bottom picture is the case shown.

```
spacemodel = 
     SystemModelLinearize["DocumentationExamples.Modeling.Generator", 
       Method -> {"SymbolicDerivative", 
           "SymbolicParameters" -> {"R1", "R2", "L"}}]
    R1 = 10;
    R2 = 20;
    L = 0.02;
    A = spacemodel[[1, 1]]
    B = spacemodel[[1, 2]]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I get an error when I run your first line of code  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8QUd.png)  `SystemModelLinearize::bld: Failed to build model DocumentationExamples.Modeling.Generator.`  V 13.1  Where is this thing called `"DocumentationExamples.Modeling.Generator"` ??

Comment: （https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemModelLinearize.html.zh）You can open this URL. This routine is roughly in the middle of the page.

Comment: It does not work.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnrEQ.png)  `SystemModelLinearize::bld: Failed to build model DocumentationExamples.Modeling.InvertedPendulum.Components.DCMotor.`  V 13.1 on windows.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x5IH.png)  `SystemModelLinearize::bld: Failed to build model DocumentationExamples.Modeling.InvertedPendulum.Components.DCMotor.`

Comment: I guess it may be the version problem. I used Mathematica 13.0

Comment: it says `
[EXPERIMENTAL]` so I could have bugs.

Comment: Could you successfully open this case of the website I sent to you?

Comment: No I could not. I tried the English version of the page https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemModelLinearize.html and also the Chinese version you gave link to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemModelLinearize.html.zh  and both give error on my version of Mathematica.

Comment: Think about the following: 1. Is it really necessary to include definition of `spacemodel` to reproduce your problem? 2. Under [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/276344/1871) I said the answer is already there, what does this mean? Which response am I refering to?

Comment: Ok I think it's really about the version. Can you easily ask which version of Mathematica you are using？

Comment: I have such a requirement to assign values to variables in the resulting matrix. but I cannot assign values to variables of this type(Quantity variable) in the actual matrix.

Comment: @Nasser To use these functions, a VS C++ compiler is necessary, you need to first execute ``SystemModelConfiguration`InstallCompiler[]`` to configure the compiler properly. (If `Method` option isn't added to `SystemModelLinearize`, there will be a warning message about this. )

Comment: @xzczd wow. So now one needs VS C++ compiler to evaluate some Mathematica commands? I do not like this at all. So I will not use such commands.  I do not think this is good idea for WRI to do this. But that is for another place.  btw, I looked again at the above webpage and I see no mention that one needs  to install extra software to use these commands. But may be I missed that. ps. I never used systemModels before in Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser Yeah, to be precise, VS C++ in Windows, Xcode in Mac and G++/Clang in Linux. This seems to be mentioned only in the tutorial [_Compiler for System Modeling_](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CompilerForSystemModeling.html) at the moment. I don't like this design, either. (At least let me choose the compiler, g++ and clang are also available in Windows! )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for comment, but can you use these replacements for your symbolic variables? If not, then add a desirable output for `A` and `B` to your post.

```
R1 = Quantity[10, "Ohms"];
R2 = Quantity[20, "Ohms"];
L = Quantity[0.02, "Henries"];

rule1 = {QuantityVariable["R1", IndependentPhysicalQuantity[""]] -> 
   R1, QuantityVariable["R2", IndependentPhysicalQuantity[""]] -> R2, 
  QuantityVariable["L", IndependentPhysicalQuantity[""]] -> L}

A1 = spacemodel[[1, 1]] /. rule1 // UnitSimplify // FullSimplify
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0. & 1. & 0. \\
 0. & 0. & 0. \\
 0. & 50./\text{H} & -1500.\text{Hz} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think your answer can meet my needs!